# Run code when a Datagrid checkbox is checked/unchecked, and get the changed value

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I need to execute code when a checkbox on a datagrid is check/unchecked, theres not much else to say.

So I have:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        txtCCs.Text = String.Empty;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CC.Name].Value) == true)
            {
                txtCCs.Text += row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim() + ", ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Which works in a new bare project, but noy my actual project, where it runs but doesn't see the changed value. So if I click 1 box, nothing happens, click another it can now see the first is checked, but misses the one that was clicked to trigger it. Even though I have the CommitEdit in my code.

Edit: I completely removed the CellContentClick code and remove the function and now it works. Not sure what the issue was, as it would still run, just not do the commitEdit.

Comment: does the value `= true` or does it `= "true"` as a string..? when you add break points does it hit the code that you have posted.

Comment: The function doesn't run when the checkbox is clicked, but after it has been ticked, and I click the same row, the function will run and the value will = true as a bool and do its thing.

Comment: checkout the [msdn documentation - DataGridView.CellContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you a bot, as I've explicitly said that is not what I need and doesn't work. The page even says it doesn't work for checkboxes. It does mention "CellValueChanged" however, which I am trying to get to work, but when I place the code I show in my post in the "CellValueChanged" function, it gives and error saying "Index was out of range" which I don't understand as it should function to same as the cellContentClick which gives no errors.

Comment: Your going to need to post more code for anyone to figure it out.  I would recommend posting the code where you initialize the grid and set it's properties and also any other grid events that you are hooked up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit the edit first:

```
void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
  txtCCs.Text = String.Empty;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CC.Name].Value) == true) {
      txtCCs.Text += row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim() + ", ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that just does what I currently have, it just does not see the changed value. The code runs, but it just doesn't see the value as anything different.

Comment: @Tom That's not what I'm seeing.  Every check mark change I make is updating the text instantly on the screen.

Comment: I do feel theres just something messing with it, but I have a real basic form, and its functioning like I've said :/

Comment: @Tom Per your comment from the top of your question, CellContentClick will run when you click on the checkbox.  Do you have the event properly wired up?

Comment: I would agree with @LarsTech that something else is interfering.  If your `.Cells[3]` column has values already in their cells then you should be seeing the string update with all the checked rows - including the row you just checked.  I confirmed it is working using the `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: Previously I tried a CellContentClick event, I had it checking if the clicked rows CheckBox == true. and then have a text box say "x" else say "Y". When the checkbox was checked/unchecked it did nothing, but if I then clicked a cell of a row text would appear. So very much for me checking a checkbox doesn't trigger CellContentClick

Comment: @Tom That's why you have to call the CommitEdit method.

Comment: I just made a new project and just had a datagrid and textbox and your solution worked, as did the one I have posted. So there is something in my other project interfering and I have no idea what could. Compared to this new project I made, when I check the box on my main project it takes around 1-2 seconds for it to check. Where as on new project it is all instant. Not if the time delay is an issue, or why.

Comment: I just deleted the CellContentClick event from the project completely, so from the .Designer and base .cs and remade it and it has sorted the problem. Dunno why it did it. Thank for your help :)